# Is it possible for the libero to score points in volleyball?

Tags: rules, scoring, volleyball

Is it possible for a libero to score points during a volleyball match?

I believe that libero cannot hit the ball, but he can set and receive, so is it possible that the ball passes over the net and falls in the opposite field?

Is there any example of the libero scoring points by the end of the match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible for a libero to score point during a volleyball match?

Yes. There is nothing in [the rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp), in particular Rule 19 "The Libero Player", which says that a libero cannot score points.

> The libero cannot hit the ball

This is incorrect. Quoting from Rule 19.3.1.2:

> [The Libero] is not allowed to complete an attack hit from anywhere [...] **if at the moment of the contact the ball is entirely higher than the top of the net**.

(my emphasis) i.e. the libero can hit the ball, so long as it's done from below the height of the net.

> There is any exemple with the libero with points at the end of the match?

Yes - you can see some examples of Japan's libero, [Arisa Satō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arisa_Sat%C5%8D), scoring points in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xKGdQhTgGE).

Comment: While your example is fine as well, [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=etL5WETiLuE) is the most entertaining example for sure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Japan's libero Arisa Sato seems good at scoring, see the video at youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xKGdQhTgGE

Comment: Looks like this information was already covered in the accepted answer.

Comment: @New-To-It actually, no. I edited this information into my answer after it was posted here, so that we have one definitive answer to the question.